# Difference between a clickable ImageView and ImageButton

Tags: android, android-imageview, imagebutton

I'm just wondering if there is any significant difference between an `ImageView` that's set to be clickable, compared with an `ImageButton`?

Is there any reason for using one over the other? Is there any restriction on the drawable for an `ImageButton` that leaves `ImageView` as the only possible option?

Will I possibly lose any functionality of a button if I opt for a clickable `ImageView` over `ImageButton`?

Answer (score 168, accepted):

There are no differences, except default style. `ImageButton` has a non-null background by default.

**EDIT**: Also, `ImageButton.onSetAlpha()` method always returns false, `scaleType` is set to `center` and it's always inflated as focusable.

Here's `ImageButton`'s default style:

```
 <style name="Widget.ImageButton">
     <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
     <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
     <item name="android:scaleType">center</item>
     <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/btn_default</item>
 </style>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You gave me more than I spotted when going through the code myself. I guess end of the day, selection between the 2 will depend on how much of the default properties you can use without any customization.

Comment: You're welcome! Yeah, there isn't much difference indeed, so the choice is between button and not button, I think.

Comment: Actually in my experience another difference between the two is that if you want to put a clickable button into a ListView´s cell while maintaining the cell itself as clickable you are much better off with an Imageview. EditTexts and ImageButtons seem to consume the touch event when TextViews and ImageViews don´t.

Comment: I had used clickable ImageView but as per new requirement I have to change them to ImageButton but the image used gets Inflated. How can i avoid the image inflation in ImageButton ?

Comment: @codeRider I'm not sure I understand what you mean. If it's positioning differs from what it was in `ImageView` you can and specify `scaleType` explicitly.

Answer (score 26):

ImageButton is inherited from ImageView

```
public class ImageButton extends ImageView {
public ImageButton(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public ImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, com.android.internal.R.attr.imageButtonStyle);
}

public ImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    setFocusable(true);
}

@Override
protected boolean onSetAlpha(int alpha) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    super.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(event);
    event.setClassName(ImageButton.class.getName());
}

@Override
public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(AccessibilityNodeInfo info) {
    super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(info);
    info.setClassName(ImageButton.class.getName());
}
```

as @Micheal describe i just add details to his answer

Comment: How does this answer the various questions in the OP?

Comment: @flawyte it doesn't - it just extends the accepted answer with just how `ImageButton` derives from `ImageView`.

Answer (score 8):

The effect of a button click when I click is there for imagebutton but not for imageView.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can give the button clic effect as a background. ImageButton has an effect by default.