# When to use ImageButton rather than ImageView?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a confusion about `ImageButton`. I can make an `ImageView` clickable and use as button, so why do we explicitly need an `ImageButton`? When designing Android app, I found `ImageView` is much more useful than `ImageButton`, perhaps I missed some of the features of `ImageButton`. So I want to know what are the advantages of using `ImageButton`? Thanks.

Comment: Already asked : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847136/difference-between-a-clickable-imageview-and-imagebutton

Comment: Damnit a minute too late! Oh well... You can check out this previous answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847136/difference-between-a-clickable-imageview-and-imagebutton

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question was answered quite thoroughly here: [Difference between a clickable ImageView and ImageButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847136/difference-between-a-clickable-imageview-and-imagebutton)

To sum it up: There's no differences, except default style. ImageButton has a non-null background by default.