# How to create image button in android?

Tags: java, android, button, android-activity, imagebutton

So I'm new to android development...How can I create an image that acts like button, so when I press that image, image starts a specific activity.
So I want this to show as image:

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: you mean an ImageButton http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html

Comment: There is a control specifically for this in Android. Do a google  search before posting your question..

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Create ImageButton as:

**In main.xml:**

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/ib"
    android:src="@drawable/bookmark" <-- SET BUTTON IMAGE HERE -->
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

**In Code part:**

```
ImageButton ib=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ib);
ib.setOnClickListener(ibLis);
    }
    private OnClickListener ibLis=new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //START YOUR ACTIVITY HERE AS
             Intent intent = new Intent(YOUR_CURRENT_ACTIVITY.this,NextActivity.class);
             startActivity(intent, 0);
        }
    };
```

**EDIT:**

and second option if you want to create an image like button using Button View then Create an Custom button as:

First put your all images like for pressed,focused and default in res/drawable folder and then add an newbtn.xml in drawable/newbtn.xml as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <item android:state_pressed="true"  
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->  
    <item android:state_focused="true"  
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->  
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->  
</selector>
```

Finally in button XML set `android:background` as :

```
<Button    
    android:id ="@+id/btn"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:text="Hello"  
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"  
    android:background="@drawable/newbtn"   <-- get button background to selector -->
    />
```

See this tutorial for Creating Custom Button with images

[Creating custom, fancy buttons in Android](http://www.thesecretpie.com/2010/07/creating-custom-fancy-buttons-in.html)

Comment: @user1414682: make sure you have register second activity in manifest as <Activity android:name=".NextActivity" />

Comment: I found the problem: I had android:text="Button" and android:src="@drawable/bookmark" in code, so I removed "text" Thanks!

Comment: Just one more question, can I use animated image?

Comment: you can use `AnimationDrawable`  for animating you image button but i'm not sure. so just make a search on google about A`nimationDrawable` maybe this will help u.thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With the ImageView element, attaching a click listener to it.

The XML:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/myPic" 
    />
```

The code:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ThisActivity.this, MyOtherActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

You also could use a ImageButton (in the same way). It makes almost no difference. You can see more details here. [Difference between a clickable ImageView and ImageButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847136/difference-between-a-clickable-imageview-and-imagebutton)

Answer (score 0):

It's an overcomplication to use "setOnClickListener()".  Instead, use the 'onClick' property in XML:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button19"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:onClick="yourCallback"
    android:src="@drawable/your_image"
/>

public void yourCallback(View view) 
{
    ...
}
```