# Android (eclipse) image button vs background image

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to figure out which is best to use.

I'm trying to develop a simple game and designing the starting activity. to start the game I plan to have a start button.
I want to use a custom design though.

My question is, should I use an `ImageButton` (which I believe is an imported image that you can click on, or a textview with `android:background="@drawable/imageName"`.
Both seem to allow onClick if I'm not mistaken so what's the pros and or one over the other?

Hope this isn't duplicate question, all I found was info on how to upload images which I don't need. Just need to know advantages to using one versus the other.

also, Does onclick for textview apply to background or only text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think imagebutton maybe better.
because you must have a click effect for feedback . if you use background for the image ,you have to write a selector.xml for change the click and unclick effects.
so, i think imagebutton may be better.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. I put both into a fragmentactivity and the text highlights when hover and image only on click.  I didn't think of that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `android:src="@drawable/imageName"`

So that the image will be perfect fit. Also you can use

```
  android:scaleType="fitCenter"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

If you are using `TextView` then your background may not be good

Answer (score 1):

From : [Difference between a clickable ImageView and ImageButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847136/difference-between-a-clickable-imageview-and-imagebutton)

There's no differences, except default style. ImageButton has a non-null background by default.

Also, `ImageButton.onSetAlpha()` method always returns false, scaleType is set to center and it's always inflated as focusable.

Here's ImageButton's default style:

```
 <style name="Widget.ImageButton">
     <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
     <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
     <item name="android:scaleType">center</item>
     <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/btn_default</item>
 </style>
```