# Button or clickable imageview?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am debating whether to use a button OR Clickable Image view and I am not sure which way is the best?

I basically want to add buttons on my screens (a fancy nice looking button like the ones you see in games). I have the image of the button. I can either create an imageview and make it clickable or create a button and set the background to the image?

Both seems to work and both I can set the width and height to as I like. Any reason for why use one versus another in my case?
Thank you

Comment: Has been answered before here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847136/difference-between-a-clickable-imageview-and-imagebutton

Comment: I am not asking about ImageButton. I am asking about Button which is a totally different inheritance

Comment: It depends on the size and positioning of those clickable items. So show or explain the blueprint, if you can.

Comment: @Psy Duck.. What do you mean? It is 3 buttons under each other in the middle of the screen. You can say the button size is 70 by 70 dp

Comment: Buttons might loose the quality of the images that you are about to use, unless they are vector images (9 patched). So I guess you should make images according to the size you want and then use them on button. If they are not 9patched/vector, use them on ImageButton or ImageView.

Comment: Thank you.. So games use images view then most of the time? Feel free to out it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference between them is that a button has different push states(pressed, selected, focussed etc.) that you can use, while a clickable ImageView doesn't.

Comment: Thank you so which one do games use?   buttons such as cash button, fight button.. Etc

Comment: I think most of the games use ImageButton, as it can display an image as ImageView and can have push states as well.

Comment: But imgaebutton load the image within a grey border.Also wouldn't button with background image do the same?

Comment: The border can be disabled by setting the ImageButton's background to null. And yes, a button can have a background but ImageButton has more methods to control the image. Also, with an ImageButton you can set a foreground and a background image.