# Differentiate between ImageButton and ImageView?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

It is little bit confusing between ImageView and ImageButton. I think both have mostly same XML attributes. Does any effect to the app if i use ImageView instead of ImageButton?

Comment: ImageButton has a non-null background by default. Except this, there's no difference.

Comment: if there is no difference between them, why both are separated?#peter haddad

Comment: For ImageView you have to add onClick property for clickevent. But ImageButton you dont require  it as it provides the property of button.

Comment: already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847136/difference-between-a-clickable-imageview-and-imagebutton

Comment: as I said, ImageButton has a non-null background and ImageView doesn't. If you use an ImageButton you might see a button like feel in the background where ImageView has just an image.

Comment: 1. button - 3d rendering of a button that has text. Very simple easy to use. 2. ImageButton - 3d rendeirng of a button but instead of text you are using an image. 3. ImageView - a flat image

Answer (score 1):

Only the default style is the difference among ImageButton & ImageView. ImageButton has a non-null background by default.
**Default properties of ImageButton:**

- ImageButton.onSetAlpha() method always returns false.
- It's scaleType is set to center, and
- It's always inflated as focusable.

Answer (score 0):

Displays a button with an image (instead of text) that can be pressed or clicked by the user. By default, an ImageButton looks like a regular Button, with the standard button background that changes color during different button states. The image on the surface of the button is defined either by the android:src attribute in the  XML element or by the setImageResource(int) method.

Src [ImageButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html)

ImageButton is inheriting from ImageView. By default, Image button will be having imageButtonStyle as style. Have a look on source code of ImageButton

```
public class ImageButton extends ImageView {
public ImageButton(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public ImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, com.android.internal.R.attr.imageButtonStyle);
}

public ImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    this(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, 0);
}

public ImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    setFocusable(true);
}

@Override
protected boolean onSetAlpha(int alpha) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getAccessibilityClassName() {
    return ImageButton.class.getName();
}
}
```