# FFImageLoading : load into an ImageButton

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, ffimageloading

In Xamarin.Android, to load an image using FFImageLoading, a ImageViewAsync must be used instead of a standard ImageView.

I couldn't find what I can use if I wanna load my image into an ImageButton. Didn't find an "ImageButtonAsync".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no particular `ImageButton` to use with FFImageLoading but you can use directly an `ImageViewAsync` set it as `android:clickable="true"` and add the click event.

And as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847136/difference-between-a-clickable-imageview-and-imagebutton?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) an `ImageButton` is just an `ImageView` that has a non-null background by default and also, ImageButton.onSetAlpha() method always returns false, scaleType is set to center and it's always inflated as focusable. So if you need that behaviour you can add it.

Another way would be you to create your custom `ImageButton` that can handle FFImageLoading image loading. For that you can inherit from `ImageViewAsync` and add the behaviours explained in the paragraph before. So that you can use the FFImageLoading API directly as this custom controls inherits `ImageViewAsync`.

Instead of that you can also add your custom loading logic as explained [here](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Advanced-Usage) inheriting from `ImageLoaderTask` and call it like `ImageService.Instance.LoadImage(customImageTask)`

Finally another way (but hackish and non-performant) would be to create an `ImageViewAsync` just to hold the result of the FFImageLoading and on the Success callback set the Drawable in the `ImageButton`:

```
var myImageButton = myView.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.my_image_button);
var myImageView = new ImageViewAsync(this); // this is the context
ImageService.Instance.LoadUrl(this.Source[position].LogoImagePath)
                .Success(() => myImageButton.SetImageDrawable(myImageView.Drawable))
                .Into(myImageView);
```

HIH and if you need any help let me know

Answer (score 5):

Dont know if this is relevant or not. I gave my svg a tap gesture to get it working like a button.

first reference the FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms in your xaml

```
namespace:FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms"
```

second add the svgImage with a tap gesture

```
    <ffimageloadingsvg:SvgCachedImage Source="YourImageSource" >
                    <ffimageloadingsvg:SvgCachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Command="{Binding YourCommand}"/>
                    </ffimageloadingsvg:SvgCachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
    </ffimageloadingsvg:SvgCachedImage>
```

You will call this in the constructor of your ViewModel to initialize the command

```
YourCommand= new DelegateCommand(async () => await ExecuteYourCommandAsync());
```

Create the properties that bind to the xaml file

```
    public ICommand YourCommand
    {
        get => yourCommand;
        set => SetProperty(ref yourCommand, value);
    }

    private ICommand yourCommand;
```

The await ExecuteYourCommandAsync is a method that you create. and in there you will put your logic of what you actually want the tap gesture to do.

You can also pass through object with the command. let met know if this makes sense

Comment: I Have updated my answer to show what the command would look like on the ViewModel of your page