# Loading FFImageLoading SVG into ImageButton Source from code?

Tags: xamarin.forms, ffimageloading

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49819295/ffimageloading-load-into-an-imagebutton) shows how to make SvgCachedImage act like a button. However, how to load SvgCachedImage into XamarinForm's ImageButton Source ?

My non-working code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SharedSvgSample"
             x:Class="SharedSvgSample.MainPage"
             xmlns:ffimageloadingsvg="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms">
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <ImageButton
            x:Name="myButton"
            HeightRequest="200"
            Clicked="myButton_Clicked"
            WidthRequest="200" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Code-behind:

```
using FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms;
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace SharedSvgSample
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private bool _myButtonValue;
        private SvgImageSource _visibilityOn = null;
        private SvgImageSource _visibilityOff = null;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _visibilityOn = SvgImageSource.FromResource("SharedSvgSample.Resources.visibility_on.svg");
            _visibilityOn.VectorHeight = 100;
            _visibilityOn.VectorWidth = 100;

            _visibilityOff = SvgImageSource.FromResource("SharedSvgSample.Resources.visibility_off.svg");
            _visibilityOff.VectorHeight = 100;
            _visibilityOff.VectorWidth = 100;

            myButton.Source = _visibilityOff;   
        }

        private void myButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _myButtonValue = !_myButtonValue;
            myButton.Source = _myButtonValue ? _visibilityOn.ImageSource : _visibilityOff.ImageSource;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As I know, FFImageLoading SVG and Image button are different controls, and you can set only the ImageButton image source.
Why can't you use FFImageLoading SVG with tap gesture event?

Comment: I am confused here these are two different controls what exactly are you trying to achieve here

Comment: @G.hakim I am trying to have ImageButton to load SVG icon.

Comment: @ДенисЧорный , with FFImageLoading SVG with tap gesture event, I lost features of ImageButton (such as setting rounded border, etc). The workaround I am looking for is to have FFImageLoading to prerender an image on-memory that ImageButton can accept.

Comment: Well i don't know if you can do that, I am pretty sure you can't but goodluck finding it

Comment: @JesonMartajaya would be interesting to see what would you achieve in your issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Unluckily, `Xamarin.Forms.Button` only supports FileImageSource, so at the moment you can't just load an SVG into the Button Image.

However, you can just load the SVG image, and add the TapGestureRecognizer to simulate a Button.

Comment: I am referring to `Xamarin.Forms.ImageButton`. I am more looking into workaround in having FFImageLoading prerenders svg icon in-memory to an image that ImageButton can accept.

Comment: @JesonMartajaya did you find a solution for this?